# print list of dictonaries to template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

this may be silly question, But newbie here, need some help

I need to print dictionary to template

```
template_var = {}
settings = Article.objects.filter().values('title','content')
for some in settings:
    pprint.pprint(some)
```

the output of console log is

```
{'content': u'add blog ', 'title': u'blog here'}
{'content': u'fweferwgfwefw', 'title': u'few'}
{'content': u'fsvbfsvbsfvsdfv', 'title': u' fsfsbfsbvsfvb'}
```

this is the way i am passing `some` to `template_var['article']= some`. And in my html i do like this

```
{% for content in some %}
    {{ content }}
{% endfor %}
```

but that's not working.

Comment: How is not working? Does it display nothing? or does it show you error? Does it print unexpected stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating `settings` in the `for` statement:

```
for some in settings:
    pprint.pprint(some)
```

But, the view code is passing `some` instead of `settings` to the template, and iterating it. In addition to that, the code is passing the variable as `article`, but it is used as `some` in the template.

Make them to be consistent:

**view**

```
template_var['settings'] = settings
```

**template**

```
{% for some in settings %}
    {{ some }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: cool, that's working now. can i ask one question not from this one. See `Article` model foreignkey with User, So i can able to filter only by user_id only but in html i just want the username or firstname to printed like some.username..? how can i get that ?

Comment: @iask, `Article.objects.filter().values('title','content', 'user__username', 'user__firstname')`; Now you can access the username, firstname in the template. ; `{{ some.user__username }} / {{ some.user__firstname }}`

Comment: if am doing like that i'm getting `Cannot resolve keyword, choices are user, user_id`

Comment: @iask, Ah, my mistake. It should be double underscore: `user__username`, `user__firstname`.

Comment: yah ... working .. yesterday also you helped. You are really helped me to learn..

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print the dictonary to templates the you can do

in viwes.py

```
return render(request, "template.html", { 'settings' : settings})
```

and in template.html

this is for getting entire dictonary

```
{% for set1 in settings %}
  {{set1}}
{% endfor %}
```

and this is for getting each element of dictonary

```
   {% for set1 in settings %}
          {{set1.content}}<br/>
{{set1.title}}
        {% endfor %}
```